# Why does using Comparable as my passed in parameter type not work?

Tags: java, types, parameters, linked-list, nodes

I am having trouble with my class, AbstractListNode, which is supposed to implement the nodes of a singly linked list. I have a method that compares if two lists are equal, in size and in each item of the nodes. However, I have found that if I use the Comparable type for the object passed in, the method does not work, whereas if I make the type AbstractListNode, the method works. Can anyone help me understand why this is? The lab I am working on says that we should be typing the parameter as Comparable.

```
public boolean equals(Comparable item){  


        boolean isEqual = false;  
        AbstractListNode compare = (AbstractListNode) item;  
        int thisSize = size();  
        int compareSize = compare.size();  
        if (thisSize == compareSize){      
            AbstractListNode thisItem = this;  
            while (!thisItem.isEmpty()){  
                if(thisItem.item().equals(compare.item())){                     
                    isEqual = true;  
                    compare = compare.next();  
                    thisItem = thisItem.next();  
                }else{  
                    isEqual = false;  
                }  
            }  
            System.out.println(isEqual);  
        }
```

Comment: So, uh, why are you taking `Comparable`? Also, if the instructions are telling you to make `equals` take a `Comparable`, your class is horrible. I hope you just misunderstood the instructions.

Comment: `equals` should always take type `Object`.

Comment: Ok, using Object works. That is how I originally had the type, but here are the instructions from my lab. "Change the type of list elements in AbstractListNode, NonemptyListNode and EmptyListNode from Object to Comparable. (This means that any Objects stored in myItem will need to implement Comparable methods that you will be able to take advantage of)." It's from the Berkeley CS61BL course.

Comment: That's not telling you to make `equals` take type `Comparable`.

Comment: Oh wow, I misunderstood that because the next method is supposed to take Comparable as the type. Thanks. But, why would using Comparable as the type now work? I don't understand the reasoning.

Comment: The arguments you're passing to `equals` aren't `Comparable`s. Even if you change that (you shouldn't), the static type of the arguments will frequently just be `Object`, and overload resolution works by static type.

Comment: So I assume you start with your `NonemptyListNode` and have a constructor `public NonemptyListNode(Object item)` or some such; it seems , per the instructions, you would change that to `public NonemptyListNode(Comparable item)` and make whatever other changes necessary from doing that.